# Access current font settings from Lua

Tags: fonts, luatex, context

I’d like to write some current settings to a file, using `io.savedata`.
How can I get information about the current font, or even better, the current settings for `\rm`, `\ss` and `\tt`?

EDIT: fontconfig must be able to cope with the font name. I want to pass the font from ConTeXt to GNU LilyPond.
See http://wiki.contextgarden.net/LilyPond

Comment: Did you share your code? I'm currently testing a reimplementation of lilypond-book in latex. Maybe we can combine our forces.

Answer (score 6):

> How can I get information about the current font

The font object contains some more information read from the font
file. You can access it in the `metadata` table e. g.:

```
\startluacode
  local font_info = function (id)
    local fnt = font.getfont(id)
    context.section { title = fnt.resources.filename }
    local metadata = fnt.shared and fnt.shared.rawdata and fnt.shared.rawdata.metadata
    if not metadata then return end
    local out = function (k)
      local v = metadata [k]
      context (k) context ": "
      context (v) context.endgraf()
    end
    local items = table.keys (metadata)
    context "id: " context (id) context.endgraf()
    for i=1, \letterhash items do out (items [i]) end
  end
  userdata.current_font_info = function () font_info (font.current()) end
\stopluacode

\def \showfontinfo {\ctxlua {userdata.current_font_info ()}}

\setupbodyfont [10pt]
\setuphead [section] [style=\tf]
\starttext
  \showfontinfo \endgraf
  \tt \showfontinfo \endgraf
  \definedfont[file:iwona-regular.otf at 10pt] \showfontinfo \endgraf
  \definedfont[file:antykwatorunska-bold.otf at 10pt] \showfontinfo \endgraf
\stoptext
```

[image: font info dump]

> fontconfig must be able to cope with the font name

You can create [patterns for
fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-devel/fcpatternformat.html)
from the abovementioned table. Information pertaining to the font
definition (e. g. the font size in sp) can be accessed in the
`specification` table.

```
\startluacode

  local get_metadata = function (id)
    local fnt = font.getfont(id)
    if fnt then
      return fnt.shared and fnt.shared.rawdata and fnt.shared.rawdata.metadata
    end
  end

  local get_size = function (id)
    local fnt = font.getfont(id)
    if fnt then return fnt.specification.size end
  end

  local fc_pattern = function (id)
    local metadata = get_metadata (id)
    local size = get_size (id)
    if not metadata then return "nil" end
    local ret = string.format ([[\letterpercent s:\letterpercent s]],
                               metadata.familyname,
                               metadata.subfamily)
    if size then ret = ret .. ":size=" .. tostring(size / 2^16) end
    return ret
  end

  userdata.print_fc_pattern = function () print (fc_pattern (font.current())) end
  userdata.current_fc_pattern = function () return fc_pattern (font.current()) end

\stopluacode

\def \showfcpattern {%
  \fontname \font
  \rightarrow
  “\ctxlua {context (userdata.current_fc_pattern ())}”
  %ctxlua {userdata.print_fc_pattern ()}
  \endgraf
}

\setupbodyfont [10pt]

\starttext
  \showfcpattern \endgraf
  \tt \showfcpattern \endgraf
  \definedfont[file:iwona-regular.otf at 10pt] \showfcpattern \endgraf
  \definedfont[file:antykwatorunska-bold.otf at 10pt] \showfcpattern \endgraf
\stoptext
```

Combine the information from both tables to create suitable
patterns for Fontconfig.

[image: example fc patterns]

The strings from above snippet can then be fed into `fc-match(1)`
and the likes and probably Lilypond too:

```
$ fc-match "Iwona:Regular:size=10"
iwona-regular.otf: "Iwona" "Regular"
$ fc-match "Antykwa Torunska:Bold:size=10"
antykwatorunska-bold.otf: "Antykwa Torunska" "Bold"
$ fc-match "Latin Modern Roman:Regular:size=10"
lmroman10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "10 Regular"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the closest I could get.  You have to extract the font ID on the TeX level with `\fontid\font` and pass it to Lua.  There you can then extract the font name and identifier.  As I don't know exactly what you want to do with it, parsing and stuff is up to you.  The return values of `tex.fontname` and `tex.fontidentifier` are regular Lua strings.

```
\def\getfontnames{%
  \startluacode
    function printothers(text)
      local catcodetableothers = -2
      tex.sprint(catcodetableothers, text)
    end

    context.startTABLE()
      context.NC() context("tex.fontname")
      context.NC() printothers(tex.fontname(\fontid\font))
      context.NC() context.NR()
      context.NC() context("tex.fontidentifier")
      context.NC() printothers(tex.fontidentifier(\fontid\font))
      context.NC() context.NR()
    context.stopTABLE()
  \stopluacode
}

\starttext
\rm\getfontnames

\it\getfontnames

\tt\getfontnames
\stoptext
```

[image]